# Mobile Usability data via the Google Search Console API

Tags: google-api, google-search-api, google-search-console

I want to extract all 15k pages in this Mobile Usability report but the web app console only lets me get 1k.

[image]

For other reports I can get all the data using the API but I can't find a Mobile Usability method.

[image]